# message An exception occurred processing JSP page /second.jsp at line 18

Tags: java, jsp

I have jsp page on which I got this type of error, please suggest me where i am getting wrong...

```
<body>
    <%!
    Student studentinfo;
    StudentDAO std;
    %>
   <%
   String id =request.getParameter("ID1");
   std.searchinfo(id);
   out.println("<h1>" +studentinfo.showStudent()+ "</h1>");
  %>

</body>
```

this is the error..

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: please suggest me which is line 18?

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /second.jsp at line 18

15:         %>
16:        <%
17:        String id =request.getParameter("ID1");
18:        std.searchinfo(id);
19:        out.println("<h1>" +studentinfo.showStudent()+ "</h1>");
20:       %>
21:

Comment: 18: std.searchinfo(id);

Answer (score 0):

The `std` variable is not initialized. You should initialize it.

I guess something like `std = new StudentDAOImpl();`

The same for `studentinfo` btw.